# Matrix Inversion time

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have generated a symmetric (topelitz) matrix in matlab.

- for matrix size 3200x3200 matrix inversion time is 5.8 sec
- for matrix size 5000x5000 matrix inversion time is 70.7 sec
- for matrix size 7200x7200 matrix inversion time is 1700 sec

Can anybody please tell me the reason of this exponential growth. I have studied that it requires N^3 operations to find the inverse but not able to make out.

Actually I am constructing the matrix using MoM and for 9800x9800 matrix size I am getting error "out of memory". So what is the solution to this problem?

Thankyou

Comment: Perhaps you're using so much memory that you're forcing the OS to use swap.

Comment: A 7200x7200 matrix would only consume ~400MB of memory. Does the MATLAB inverse command greatly increase the amount of memory used?

Comment: Measure the execution time of a wider range of matrix sizes.  Plot the graph of execution time against size.  The discontinuities in the graph are likely to be the impact of the memory hierarchy on the computation: cache effects (one effect per cache level), and, as @OliCharlesworth suggests, swapping from RAM to disk (the penultimate step in the memory hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons why you seem to find , for example:

1. Given the structure of your matrix, you do not always get the worst case calculation cost
2. Your timings are insufficient
3. The slow timing is not the result of the calculation itself

I have done a quick test myself, and so far it seems to behave quite like O(N^3), rather less steep than exponential.

```
mySize = (1:10:100).^2;
timings = [];
for isize=mySize 
    disp(isize)
    M = rand(isize);
    tic
    inv(M);
    t= toc;
    timings = [timings;t];
end


plot(mySize,timings)
hold all
plot(mySize,mySize.^1.5/mean(mySize.^1.5)*mean(timings))
```

Comment: I fixed the code and ran it. Why did you add a `n^1.5` reference line? perfectly matches `n^3` on my pc.

Comment: @DanielR I assumed `N` represented the number of rows in the matrix. If it represents the amount of elements it should indeed be `^3`. Glad to hear it makes a good match.

Comment: You are right, for some reason it matches n^3 on my PC, should be n^1.5